# Introduction to first order logic for someone with a mathematical background

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request

I am looking for resources for an introduction to formal logic, with the aim of being able to understand a proof of Gödel's completeness theorem for 1st order logic.  I have some background in set theory and algebra (mathematics undergraduate degree), but I never took courses in formal logic or foundations of mathematics.

A lot of the introduction books and web resources I find are oriented toward someone with a more philosophical less mathematical background, or are very detailed in outlining the problems encountered in trying to make logical interpretations of natural language sentences.  I would be particularly interested if anyone had any recommendations of online resources (videos, or websites), as well as texts that specifically describe first order logic in a mathematically concrete and concise way.

Comment: Enderton's text "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" would be a good introduction.

Comment: I can recommend Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic - now in its 6th edition, it has been a standard textbook for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ebbinghaus, Flum, &Thomas is perfect for somebody like you. http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387942582

the goal is just what you want: Gödel's Completeness theorem.  the presentation is superb.

Comment: fwiw, it is mathematically oriented, but I (not a real mathematician) found it quite readable.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! That is just the kind of book I am looking for.

Comment: feel free to mark my answer ;)

Comment: ah right, done!